# Does Yum update running process?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, yum

I am running Fedora 20 on my desktop. When I saw the advisory about the vulnerability in bash, I checked my system out and turns out, it was vulnerable. Today, I updated my system and a new version of bash was installed. I was expecting to restart bash for the changes to take effect. But to my surprise, the update process somehow fixed *running* copy of bash.

How?

Log:
shows 2 invocations of the same command. Between the two, upgraded the system from a different xterm window.

`` bash$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo This is a test"
vulnerable
This is a test
bash$ env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo This is a test"
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x' ``

Comment: You are executing `bash` in each line. If you have upgraded, this will run the new one.

Comment: You should also restart your machine, so that daemon processes using bash can restart with the patched version.

Comment: Thank you l0b0, Tom and others. In my defense, I usually am not this dense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you split the command into two it's clearer:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable'
bash -c "echo This is a test"
```

You're running a new instance of `bash` when checking for the bug, so it's using the updated code. You should make sure to restart all your shells to ensure that you're safe.

Comment: If you run `env` without a command, it only displays the current environment (along with any name/value pairs also specified on the command line). Replacing `env` with `export` would indeed allow you to split the one-line demo into two lines.

Comment: If you run the command given it actually adds `x` to the `env` output.

Comment: Yes, but the subsequent `bash` command would not have that value of `x` in *its* environment.

Comment: That wasn't the point of the code. The point was to show that `bash` is being executed.

Comment: If it doesn't demonstrate the exploit, it's not really the same thing.

Comment: *This isn't about demonstrating the exploit.* It's about explaining what OP is seeing (deconstructing the code to explain what is actually being run). It would be the same example if OP was asking which command is actually being run.